# Which function do I need to apply to get tail of 20 for "a" group not "b" group

Tags: r, dataframe

I have modified my data frame into group "a" and "b", but currently I want to get all the tail of 20 for group a and not group b.
Here is the sample data:

```
#>      id time status displacement group
#> 1    15   1     2       3.4        a
#> 2    15   1     2       3.4        a
#> 3    15   1     2       3.4        a
#> 4    15   1     2       3.4        a
#> 5    15   1     2       3.4        a
#> 6    15   1     2       3.4        a
#> 7    15   1     2       3.4        a
#> 8    15   1     2       3.4        a
#> 9    15   1     2       3.4        b
#> 10   15   1     2       3.4        b
#> 11   15   1     2       3.4        b
#> 12   15   1     2       3.4        b
#> 13   15   1     2       3.4        b
#> 14   15   1     2       3.4        a
#> 15   15   1     2       3.4        a
#> 16   15   1     2       3.4        a
#> 17   15   1     2       3.4        a
#> 18   15   1     2       3.4        a
#> 19   15   1     2       3.4        a
#> 20   15   1     2       3.4        a
#> 21   15   1     2       3.4        a
#> 22   15   1     2       3.4        a
#> 23   15   1     2       3.4        a
#> 24   15   1     2       3.4        a
#> 25   15   1     2       3.4        a
#> 26   15   1     2       3.4        b
#> 27   15   1     2       3.4        b
#> 28   15   1     2       3.4        b
#> 29   15   1     2       3.4        b
#> 30   15   1     2       3.4        b
and so on with this pattern
```

I only want to get the tail of each group a of tail rows (say 5 rows), and group b remain the same.

Desire output:

```
#>    id time status displacement group
#> 4  15   1     2       3.4        a
#> 5  15   1     2       3.4        a
#> 6  15   1     2       3.4        a
#> 7  15   1     2       3.4        a
#> 8  15   1     2       3.4        a
#> 9  15   1     2       3.4        b
#> 10 15   1     2       3.4        b
#> 11 15   1     2       3.4        b
#> 12 15   1     2       3.4        b
#> 13 15   1     2       3.4        b
#> 14 15   1     2       3.4        a
#> 15 15   1     2       3.4        a
#> 16 15   1     2       3.4        a
#> 17 15   1     2       3.4        a
#> 18 15   1     2       3.4        a
#> 19 15   1     2       3.4        b
#> 20 15   1     2       3.4        b
#> 21 15   1     2       3.4        b
#> 22 15   1     2       3.4        b
#> 23 15   1     2       3.4        b
and so on with this pattern
```

I know I have to use the group_by function to group all the same group together
However, I know if I group them up and tail the number, it will apply all the group

How can I achieve it?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `DF` shown reproducibly in the Note at the end

**1) filter** use `filter` to choose those rows not in group `a` or have a row number within the last 5 of that group.

```
library(dplyr, exclude = c("filter", "lag"))

DF %>%
  group_by(group) %>%
  dplyr::filter(cur_group()[[1]] != "a" | row_number() > n() - 5) %>%
  ungroup
```

giving:

```
# A tibble: 15 x 5
      id  time status displacement group
   <int> <int>  <int>        <dbl> <chr>
 1    15     1      2          3.4 b    
 2    15     1      2          3.4 b    
 3    15     1      2          3.4 b    
 4    15     1      2          3.4 b    
 5    15     1      2          3.4 b    
 6    15     1      2          3.4 a    
 7    15     1      2          3.4 a    
 8    15     1      2          3.4 a    
 9    15     1      2          3.4 a    
10    15     1      2          3.4 a    
11    15     1      2          3.4 b    
12    15     1      2          3.4 b    
13    15     1      2          3.4 b    
14    15     1      2          3.4 b    
15    15     1      2          3.4 b
```

**2) group_modify** An alternative is to use `group_modify`.  Since the grouping variable is not passed to the function in `group_modify` we make a copy of it and then delete the copy at the end.  This gives the same result as (1).

```
library(dplyr, exclude = c("filter", "lag"))

DF %>%
  group_by(group2 = group) %>%
  group_modify(~ { if (.$group[1] == "a") slice_tail(., n = 5) else . }) %>%
  ungroup %>%
  select(- group2)
```

**3) by** This base R approach uses `by` and returns the tail if the group is `a` and return all the rows otherwise.  `by` produces a `by` class list so put it back together again afterwards.

```
by(DF, DF$group, function(x) if (x$group[1] == "a") tail(x, 5) else x) |>
  do.call(what = "rbind")
```

**4) subset** This is another base R approach.  We define a function which is like `seq_along` but returns the result in reverse order and then use `subset` to choose groups not equal to `a` or for which the reverse sequence number is less than or equal to 5.

```
rev_seq <-  function(x) rev(seq_along(x))
subset(DF, group != "a" | ave(seq_along(group), group, FUN = rev_seq) <= 5)
```

### Note

```
Lines <- "id time status displacement group
15   1     2       3.4        a
15   1     2       3.4        a
15   1     2       3.4        a
15   1     2       3.4        a
15   1     2       3.4        a
15   1     2       3.4        a
15   1     2       3.4        a
15   1     2       3.4        a
15   1     2       3.4        b
15   1     2       3.4        b
15   1     2       3.4        b
15   1     2       3.4        b
15   1     2       3.4        b
15   1     2       3.4        a
15   1     2       3.4        a
15   1     2       3.4        a
15   1     2       3.4        a
15   1     2       3.4        a
15   1     2       3.4        a
15   1     2       3.4        a
15   1     2       3.4        a
15   1     2       3.4        a
15   1     2       3.4        a
15   1     2       3.4        a
15   1     2       3.4        a
15   1     2       3.4        b
15   1     2       3.4        b
15   1     2       3.4        b
15   1     2       3.4        b
15   1     2       3.4        b"
DF <- read.table(text = Lines, header = TRUE)
```

### Added

If the comment below means that we want to keep only the last 5 rows of each set of consecutive rows of group `a` plus all rows of other groups then make these changes:

```
# 1
DF %>%
  group_by(subgroup = data.table::rleid(group)) %>%
  dplyr::filter(group != "a" | row_number() > n() - 5) %>%
  ungroup  %>%
  select(- subgroup)

# 2
DF %>%
  group_by(subgroup = data.table::rleid(group)) %>%
  group_modify(~ { if (.$group[1] == "a") slice_tail(., n = 5) else . }) %>%
  ungroup %>%
  select(- subgroup)

# 3
by(DF, data.table::rleid(DF$group), 
     function(x) if (x$group[1] == "a") tail(x, 5) else x) |>
  do.call(what = "rbind")

# 4
rev_seq <-  function(x) rev(seq_along(x))
subset(DF, group != "a" | 
  ave(seq_along(group), data.table::rleid(group), FUN = rev_seq) <= 5)
```

or maybe not use dplyr at all and just use data.table

```
library(data.table)

DT <- data.table(DF)
DT[, if (group[1] != "a") .SD else tail(.SD, 5), by = .(group, rleid(group))][, -2]
```

Comment: I think I did not make it clear. This code is getting the last group of the group and get last 5 rows. But I want to get last 5 rows of each group a. So for example. if first group a have 10 rows of group a 15 rows of group b and 20 rows of group a 16 rows of group b and so on. If I want to make it to 5 rows of group a 15 rows of group b and 5 rows of group a 16 rows of group b. How can I achieve? Thanks

Comment: See *Added* section at the end.

Comment: Thank you for help. I think I need to learn more about data table! I think its really powerful!

Comment: Hi @G. Grothendieck,
Can you please explain what group[1] and in the end [,-2] is?
For what I am understanding if correctly, group[1] means the next in group
and [ , -2] means all the row and the last 2 columns from the rows?
Thanks!

Comment: If v is any vector then v[1] is its first element.  If DF is any data frame or data.table then DF[, -2] is that data frame or data.table without its second column.

Answer (score 0):

If we assume your data is stored in a data.frame called `dt`:

```
a_rows <- which(dt$group == "a")
b_rows <- which(dt$group == "b")

rows <- sort(c(a_rows[(length(a_rows) - 5):length(a_rows)], b_rows)

dt[rows, ]
```

Comment: Hi Daniel, Can you explain more on sort(c(a_rows[(length(a_rows) - 5):length(a_rows)], b_rows)?
I know it will select group a and group b to stored in a_rows & b_rows. And the current output is not data frame 
Thanks.

Comment: I've expanded my answer explain how to use it. Basically, it takes the last 6 entries of a, and all of the entries of b. The `sort` is there to prevent the values from being rearranged, but if you want a before b, then you can drop it.

Answer (score 0):

You may subtract the `cumsum` of which are in group a from the total sum and compare the result with the desired tail length `atail` (in example obviously `7`) to create boolean subset.

```
atail <- 7
dat[with(dat, sum(group == 'a') - cumsum(group == 'a') + 1) <= atail |
      dat$group == 'b', ]
#    id time status displacement group
# 9  15    1      2          3.4     b
# 10 15    1      2          3.4     b
# 11 15    1      2          3.4     b
# 12 15    1      2          3.4     b
# 13 15    1      2          3.4     b
# 19 15    1      2          3.4     a
# 20 15    1      2          3.4     a
# 21 15    1      2          3.4     a
# 22 15    1      2          3.4     a
# 23 15    1      2          3.4     a
# 24 15    1      2          3.4     a
# 25 15    1      2          3.4     a
# 26 15    1      2          3.4     b
# 27 15    1      2          3.4     b
# 28 15    1      2          3.4     b
# 29 15    1      2          3.4     b
# 30 15    1      2          3.4     b
```

---

*Data:*

```
dat <- structure(list(id = c(15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 
15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 
15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L), time = c(1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), status = c(2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), displacement = c(3.4, 
3.4, 3.4, 3.4, 3.4, 3.4, 3.4, 3.4, 3.4, 3.4, 3.4, 3.4, 3.4, 3.4, 
3.4, 3.4, 3.4, 3.4, 3.4, 3.4, 3.4, 3.4, 3.4, 3.4, 3.4, 3.4, 3.4, 
3.4, 3.4, 3.4), group = c("a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", 
"a", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", 
"a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", 
"14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20", "21", "22", "23", "24", 
"25", "26", "27", "28", "29", "30"))
```

Comment: Because my data frame contains 11134 lines, how can I use this pattern to return all the data?

Comment: @user2805351 we probably should include an `|` condition if group is 'b', please see updated answer.

Comment: ohh right, it prints all the rows for group b, because of the or operator, but if I want to repeat 7 rows to each group "a" is it possible? or I have to use loop?
Because first thought I was thinking loop to loop all the row. I updated the question on the top

Comment: @user2805351 I actually used your recent update, just the tailing 7 a's are included in the result.